# Sublime 2 autocomplete html with multiple classes

Tags: html, css, class, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I don't really know how to create an html tag with multiple classes. Each time I do, I get this strange result.

If I want an anchor with classes "foo" and "bar", and I write

```
a.foo.bar
```

it turns into:

```
a.<foo class="bar"></foo>
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: You may want to check out the wonderful [Emmet](http://emmet.io) plugin for sublime. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed! It does seem like a very powerful plugin.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned by MBlanc in the comments, [Emmet](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Emmet) will do what you want.

1. [Install Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation#st2) if you haven't already
2. Open the Command Palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> in Windows and Linux, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> in OS X)
3. Type **`pci`** to bring up `Package Control: Install Package` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Type **`emmet`**, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, wait for it to install, then restart Sublime.

Now, in an HTML document, just type:

```
a.foo.bar
```

hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and it automatically expands to

```html
<a href="|" class="foo bar"></a>
```

where `|` is the cursor position. Type in your `href`, hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> again, and the cursor moves here:

```html
<a href="foobar.html" class="foo bar">|</a>
```

so you can enter the link's text.

Make sure you read through all the documentation on [emmet.io](http://emmet.io), this is an extremely powerful plugin, and once you get used to it your coding will be immensely faster.